# How to access to attributes of an element in the DataTables constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I define in my HTML an attribute `data-create-label` which I want to use in the options of the DataTables constructor to set the title of a button: `title: $(this).data("create-label"),`.

My problem is that `$(this)` refers to the page, and not to the current `$('[data-toggle="datatable"]')` on which the constructor is applied.

I'm pretty sure what I try to do can work but I lack skill in jQuery. How could I achieve to use an HTML defined data attribute in the DataTables constructor?

```html
<table id="MyTable" class="table table-striped" data-toggle="datatable" data-create-label="Label for my button">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Roles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ user.id }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">{{ user.username }}</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
          {{ responsability is not empty ? responsability.label : '-' }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$('[data-toggle="datatable"]').DataTable({
  buttons: [{
    text: '<i class="ion-md-add"></i>',
    attr: {
      title: $(this).data("create-label"),
      id: 'createButton',
      'class': 'btn btn-primary'
    },
  },],
  dom: 'fBrtp',
});
```

Comment: If you are only ever going to have one such table on a page, you could simply use `$('[data-toggle="datatable"]')` in that place again. But if it can be more than one, then I think you best just loop over the result of `$('[data-toggle="datatable"]')` using https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ Inside the callback function, you can then use `$(this)` to refer to the current element of the iteration.

Comment: Yes in some case I can have several tables on the same page.
Do you think it's a clean way to use .each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, `this` does not refer to the element you define the DataTable instance on. To get a reference to the element in order to retrieve the `data-create-label` attribute from it you could use `each()`, like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="datatable"]').each(function() {
  var $table = $(this);
  $table.DataTable({
    buttons: [{
      text: '<i class="ion-md-add"></i>',
      attr: {
        'title': $table.data("create-label"),
        'id': 'createButton',
        'class': 'btn btn-primary'
      },
    }],
    dom: 'fBrtp'
  });
});
```